# vim highlighting everything in red

Tags: python, vim, vi

I added a print line to a python script while the script was executing, and now all the text is highlighted in red when I open the file. Opening and closing the file doesn't get rid of it. Opening a second python file momentarily fixed the problem, but then closing file and reopening brought the problem back. Now it wont go away at all. Any body know what could cause this?

Comment: Let's try something really basic: try doin `:set syntax` in vim command mode.

Comment: It's still all red. It says 'syntax=python' at the bottom.

Comment: Can you paste the contents of the script?

Comment: I closed the file and reopened it and it's gone now. Maybe a bug in vim?

Comment: The output of `:scriptnames` would also be useful.

Comment: Just putting it here just in case there are other tired, exhausted people out there making silly mistakes - I just happened to accidentally call my file `myfile.json` instead of `myfile.js`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens sometimes in vim when it goes to highlight syntax on multi-line comments. Occasionally everything after the multi-line comment also becomes colored the same as the comment.

I am unsure whether this is a legit bug in vim, or in the actual syntax settings for Python (e.g. [python.vim](http://hlabs.spb.ru/vim/python.vim)), but I definitely experience this from time-to-time.

Comment: Occasional mis-highlighting in vim - provided there is no code error - should go away with Ctrl-L.

Comment: I will try that Ctrl-L thing and report back!

Comment: Confirmed that Ctrl-L did fix this a mis-highlight I experienced following a massive multi-line comment.

Comment: Thank-you @ThomasH! Can you explain why this works? You should make this an answer! I was using `:%s/s/r/g` which caused highlights in all my buffers and they wouldn't go away :cry:

Comment: @Bill Ctrl-L is meanwhile in the answer of Michael Ekoka (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15046986/127465), together with more info so that might suffice. Ctlr-L is just the general re-render command in vim, so vim would repaint the current viewport afresh. This usually helps in all situations where you have rendering artifacts (not just messed-up coloring).

Answer (score 7):

For a quick fix, you might try typing:

```
:hi Error NONE
```

And then hit Enter.

Answer (score 3):

Old thread, but hope this helps.

By mistake I did a "/." on my vim screen, which highlighted all lines in red. If I open any other file, the red highlighting stays.

Try searching for some other keyword, let's say "/word" - doesn't matter word exists or not. It restores the color.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have an unterminated multiline string.  They start and end with either three single or three double quotes.

```
''' <== this is the start of a multiline string



this is still in the string
this is the last line '''
```

Comment: I have some documentation at the top of the file in a multiline string, but it's terminated.

Comment: Perhaps something in how vim highlights files might be causing it not to realize that the string terminates.

Answer (score 2):

As per this article http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_syntax_highlighting, I mapped F12 to resync the syntax highlighting from the start of the file. It has worked better in some instances where `<ctrl-l>` didn't.

```
noremap <F12> <Esc>:syntax sync fromstart<CR>
inoremap <F12> <C-o>:syntax sync fromstart<CR>
```