# vim highlighting everything after <<< in red

Tags: unix, vim, redhat, ksh

I'm working on a KSH spcript on RedHat using VIm.  Everything after the "<<<" in the following loop is highlighted in red rather than the usual colours.

```
while read line; do
    #echo $line # TEST ONLY
    read linetype lettertype f3 group f4 <<< "${line}"
    if [[ $linetype == "let" ]]; then
        group_arr["$group"]=1
    fi
done < "/production/control/pref_file.ini"
```

This is about a quater of the way through a very long script, so I would really like to not have 2000 lines of red if possible!  How can I fix it?  Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129789/vim-highlighting-everything-in-red) perhaps it isn't recognising the end of the line with the "<<<".  Is there a way to force that?

Thanks,

Ger

Answer (score 2):

The `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/sh.vim` syntax script for shell scripts understands different shell dialects; in your case, it thinks `<<<` is an unsupported feature. Here is the relevant snippet:

```
" Here Strings: {{{1
" =============
" available for: bash; ksh (really should be ksh93 only) but not if its a posix
if exists("b:is_bash") || (exists("b:is_kornshell") && !exists("g:is_posix"))
syn match shRedir "<<<" skipwhite   nextgroup=shCmdParenRegion
endif
```

To avoid this, `:let b:is_kornshell = 1` and reinitialize syntax highlighting (e.g. via `:setf sh`), or, if you usually edit Kornshell scripts, reconfigure the syntax script default by putting

```
let g:is_kornshell = 1
```

into your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything.  I have tried creating a .vimrc, adding it to the .netrwhist file and updating directly in Vim but nothing seems change it.

Comment: Does your `syntax/sh.vim` have this condition? Some RedHat distros ship pretty outdated Vim versions; the approach might not work for older syntax scripts.

Comment: We're running the following version: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2.  Where is syntax/sh.vim?  I'll have a look

Comment: Try `/usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/sh.vim` (or check `:scriptnames` inside Vim); that Vim indeed is quite outdated. If you also have syntax script version _102_, you need to `:let g:is_bash = 1` (or upgrade to a newer Vim / syntax script).

Comment: It is in sh.vim.  It looks like were going to need to upgrade!